# Extract values from an model class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3

i'm passing my selected data from a list to a model class with there respective things. i have itemName and itemPrice and itemDescription which i pass to my model variables in a class and access that in another class. Now i want to get values out of that model and pass it to service as a parameter. i have some keys in my parameter in which i want to pass these values, the values are dynamic. This is my model class,

```
class Item : NSObject {
var totalPrice : String?
var numberOfItems : Int = 1
var itemPrice : String?
var itemName : String?
var itemID : String?
var itemId : String?
var  itemDdescription : String?
}

class ItemDataSource : NSObject {
var items = [Item]()
static let sharedInstance = ItemDataSource()
private override init() {}
}
```

This is how i'm passing values in my model,

```
 let item = Item()
    item.totalPrice = String(result)
    item.itemPrice = String(result)
    item.itemDdescription = itemDescription
    item.itemName = itemName
    item.itemID = itemID
    item.itemId = itemId
    ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items.append(item)
```

this is my parameter format that are going in my service ,

```
 "cart": [
            [
                "childs": [
                    [
                        "addon_cat_id": "0",
                        "id": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemId!,
                        "name": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemName!,
                        "next_move_id": "",
                        "price": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemPrice!,
                        "sort_order": "",
                        "type": "string"
                    ]
                ],
                "name": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemName!,
                "price": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemPrice!,
                "productid": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemId!,
                "qty": 2,
                "description": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemDdescription!
            ]
        ],
```

I want to pass all that things in parameter from my model class,and values should go to their respective keys in parameters.I'm confused that how can i pass that in their respective keys and when i pass here with index 0 it passes only 0 index values to the childs in my parameter. How can i pass my whole things that are in my model class?. if there are two items in my model class that it should make two childs in my parameter when i pass my data to it.Chid is an array that is going in parameter. How this can be done?

Comment: First, you need to set your parameter as per the no of items in the "items" array. If there are more than 1 items then you will append your cart with 2 arrays/dictionary. Then as per the ith value of the loop you can set the values to your dictionary.

Comment: i have to set parameter in my model class? and how will it increase as the items increses. @Priya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
class Item : NSObject {
    var totalPrice : String?
    var numberOfItems : Int = 1
    var itemPrice : String?
    var itemName : String?
    var itemID : String?
    var  itemDdescription : String?
}

class ItemDataSource : NSObject {
    var items = [Item]()
    static let sharedInstance = ItemDataSource()
    private override init() {}
}
var result = 20
var itemDescription = "itemDescription"
var itemName = "itemName"
var itemID = "1"

let item = Item()
item.totalPrice = String(result)
item.itemPrice = String(result)
item.itemDdescription = itemDescription
item.itemName = itemName
item.itemID = itemID
ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items.append(item)

let noOFItems = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items.count

var dict = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()


for i in 0 ..< noOFItems {


    var child: [String: Any] = ["addon_cat_id": "0",
                                "id": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[i].itemID!,
                                "name": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[i].itemName!,
                                "next_move_id": "",
                                "price":ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[i].itemPrice!,
                                "sort_order": "",
                                "type": "string"]

    var childs:[String: Any] = ["childs": child, "name": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[i].itemName!,
                                "price": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[i].itemPrice!,
                                "productid": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[i].itemID!,
                                "qty": 2,
                                "description": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[i].itemDdescription!]

    dict.append(childs)

}

let cart = ["cart": dict]
print(cart)
```

Comment: It will increament the childs according to the data in noOFItems? @Priya

Comment: Yes, try this in playground. @Awais

Comment: let me try. @Priya